# Ms-Access - There is no object in this control

Tags: ms-access-2016

I maintain legacy ms-access application. After installing 64-bit office edition, the application threw some error related to declare statements which i fixed according to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview). But still one following error remained

[image]

when I click on debug I see

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not clear to me, until I saw the TextBox detail

[image]

The MSComCtl2 class somehow [stop work](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/datepicker-access-2016/98aa7d3d-9e6d-4b19-a3be-ae3442fe9930).

The solution seems to just create new empty TextBox with Date format and native Calendar will still show, but it will fix the error.

[image]